# Can $Platform variable be modified in Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, ide

I'm running Delphi 10.4.1. The `$Platform` environment variable in my project appears to have been corrupted, as now the output application file in Win32/Debug is replaced whether I rebuild the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version of my project. Additionally, `TPath.GetLibraryPath()` now returns `...\Win32\Debug` in both the Win32 and Win64 versions of my project. This wasn't always the case. There is a `Win64\Debug` directory in my project folder that was modified yesterday.

I have not found a place to edit the value of `$Platform` in either the Delphi Global Options or the Project Options. A few StackOverflow posts suggest I will have to edit the `.dproj` file directly. This seems risky, and I want to be sure there isn't a better way before I try it.

Can someone tell me how to fix this, and perhaps shed some light on how it might have happened?

Comment: *"This seems risky"* Just make a backup of the file before you change it. Looking at the file to check if something is wrong in it is a logical thing to do anyway.

Comment: Since it’s corrupt, there’s probably nothing else then edit the .dproj file (of use version control system to look at the things that changed). But when this was a new project, as a helper you could considder making another new project and compare the .dproj files.

Comment: In the off chance that this may be your issue (HP computer related):  https://support.embarcadero.com/article/41743